# Kotlin List<List<String>> when instantiating creates 1 empty element

Tags: android, kotlin

Solving algorithm tasks and came to one interesting situation that before I did not pay attention to.

Here is example:

```
 val testList1 = mutableListOf<String>()

    testList1.add("f")
    testList1.add("n")

    Toast.makeText(this, testList1.size.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

In this code, my toast will return size 2. Which is ok and expected.
but let's take this example:

```
val testList2 = mutableListOf(mutableListOf<String>())

    testList2.add(mutableListOf("sf", "fgs"))
    testList2.add(mutableListOf("sw", "fgg"))

    Toast.makeText(this, testList2.size.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Here the toast shows size = 3 even though I added 2 elements (2 lists). So when instantiating it adds 1 emptyList as the first element.

Not a big problem to solve this, we can just:

var finalList = testList2.removeIf { it.isEmpty() }

But I am curious why this happens. Also is there any nice way to avoid it. Would like to know little bit more if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strange that `testList2` contains 3 objects. `testList2` is constructed with an initial empty list.

```kotlin
val testList2 = mutableListOf(mutableListOf<String>())

// using
public fun <T> mutableListOf(vararg elements: T): MutableList<T> =
    if (elements.size == 0) ArrayList() else ArrayList(ArrayAsCollection(elements, isVarargs = true))
```

Here, you can define an empty mutable list by these codes.

```kotlin
val testList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()

// or
val testList = mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()

// using
public inline fun <T> mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you pass to the `mutableListOf` function is the initial contents of the list it returns. Since you have nested a call of `mutableListOf()` inside the outer call to `mutableListOf()`, you are creating your list with an initial value of another MutableList.

If you want your list to start empty, don’t put anything inside the `()` when you call `mutableListOf()`.

If you construct your list this way, you need to specify the type of the list, since it won’t have an argument to infer the type from.

Either

```
val testList2 = mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()
```

or

```
val testList2: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
```

Comment: thanks for explanation I upvoted it! I had to accept ocos's answer to keep it fair since he answered 5 hours before and both answers are great :)